# Textarea wrapped in label expands beyond label end

Tags: css

With this markup:

```
<label for="example">
  <textarea id="example" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
</label>
```

The label does not expand with the textarea and hence the textarea pushes itself under the following fields in the form.

Does anyone know how to get the label to expand to the size of the textarea using CSS?

I've tried:

```
label { display: table; }
```

and all kinds of margins and padding on both the label and the textarea, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to close the text area properly, i.e with a closing </textarea> tag - though, I'm unsure of the use of label in this way - perhaps the for attribute is made redundant by enclosing the target element with the label tags. :shrugs:
Removing the </textarea> tag from the below example makes the check-box disappear, the point being that page display is broken if the tag is omitted. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <label for="cb">
        <textarea id="example" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
    </label>
    <input type='checkbox' checked='true' id='cb'/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apologies, that was a copy'n'paste error on my part, fixed. The label has a `for` attribute and wraps the text area because it works better with a greater range of screen readers.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm using Chrome and clicking anywhere on the text-area toggles the check-box. I wonder whether it's a browser or a screen-reader issue.

Comment: I've fixed it. It seems a clash between Twitter's bootstrap CSS and some CSS (`position: absolute` some children of labels) defined elsewhere were causing these problems. Turning off all the CSS rules one by one helped me find it. Thanks for bouncing ideas around with me, it helped me find the problem.